# Angular - How to wrap a dynamically loaded component in another component

Tags: angular

I would like to dynamically add components to a Angular app using the ViewContainerRef API.
The dynamically created components should be wrapped by another component within the project but I don't understand how I can do this without creating additional "wrapping components".

Ideally: I would like to define how the new component is wrapped in the component that creates the dynamic components.

Expected result in DOM:

```
<div class="container">
   <wrapping-component>
      <sub-component></sub-component>
   </wrapping-component>
   <wrapping-component>
      <sub-component></sub-component>
   </wrapping-component>
</div>
```

In order to create the structure above with my current solution I would have to create a "wrapper component" which in its turn creates the SubComponent. Is that the preferred way to solve this or are there better options?

[Angular dynamic-component-loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: If you want to avoid creating `wrapping-component`, am I correct to assume this component would be only normal HTML tags? Can't you just use a [NgSwitch](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#switching-cases-with-ngswitch) in that case?